# How to create Custom Form in magento for custom module with form helper

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to create vendor registration from for our vendor. How to create Form helper in custom form

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
<ul>
<li class="fields">

                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>
                </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

I m getting error  Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object
I need to know how can i crete form object in magento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your case is, that the function `$this->getFormData()` does not return an object to work with where you can get the e-mail from.
Does your block class derive from `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register`?

Have a look at `getFormData` in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Register.php` to see how this is done there.