# How to add new form in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm trying to add multiple user registration form in my magento. I am beginner in magento so how can i add multiple form in my magento website

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that will help you.

[How to create Custom Form in magento for custom module with form helper](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43204/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento-for-custom-module-with-form-helper)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066127/custom-forms-in-magento

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/